# Is there a flex substitute

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I just heard that flex is "abandonware". I am using it now with some difficulty, is there a replacement Regular Expression generator compatible with bison?

Comment: Flex is not "abandonware" (a term that doesn't even apply to open source software). It is actively maintained. If you're having difficulties using it, perhaps you should ask questions to resolve them?

Comment: [Here is a helpful response from the maintainer, from November 2013](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20131106144631.GA30250%40tldz.org&forum_name=flex-help). Doesn't look very abandoned to me.

Answer (score 2):

Flex isn't deprecated, I think you confused Adobe Flex (framework) and Flex (lexical analyser generator).

Comment: And even then: Flex (framework) lives on and thrives under the Apache umbrella.

Comment: Although the flex lexer is not GNU.